# How Can Connect Smart Contract In All Browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser, frontend, contract

I create Front End Web Page For Ether Smart Contract. I before Used Web3 Library And Meta Mask. Now My Web Page is Work. But When I Upload Site On Host For Using Others, When I Test My Web Page In Other  Systems And Other Browsers That Don't Used/Installed Meta Mask Extensions, I'm Getting An Error.
Please Some One Help Me  How Do I Connect A Web Page To A Contract?

I Before Used This Code For Connecting :

```js
     <script >
            if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') 
            {
                console.log('MetaMask is installed!');
            }else{
                console.log('MetaMask not installed!');
                alert("Please install Metamsk wallet first, then try again");
                 }                     
            const accounts = ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
            const account = accounts[0];
            const showAccount = document.querySelector('.showAccount');
                

            var contract;
            const accounts = ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
            const account = accountsH[0];
            const showAccount = document.querySelector('.showAccount');
                web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
                var address = "0x6246.../* My Contract Address */...5E7a";
                var abi =[/* My ABI */];
                        contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
     </script>
```

And It Work. But In Other Browsers That Meta Mask Is Inactive Or Not Installed, I See Error.
I Use Html And Java Scripts For Front End Programming.
[image]

Comment: I have designed a smart contract for the lottery. All parts of this contract work well, both in the contract and in the site section. On the site, a countdown timer and the amount of capital is deposited and the number of members is displayed, and all this information is extracted from the smart contract. . The main problem is that when a normal user visits the site, he can not see the contract information, because they did not install the Meta mask wallet and only visited the site.
How can information be extracted from smart contracts and displayed on the site without installing a wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answers to my questions.
I have to use [infura](https://infura.io/)

[check this page](https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-setup-your-dapps-to-not-use-metamask-plugin-but-sign-the-transaction-backend-b8cb8808c9ae)

and at first create project at site. and get ID

use this code

```js
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/3c6/*Your Own ID*/01753"));
```